# Connect slots from another class not working in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals, qt-slot

I have this class in `button.h`:

```
class Buttons : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Buttons();
    QVector<QPushButton*> buttons;
public slots:
    void getBtnInfo();
};
```

and in `mainwindow.cpp`, I connect like this:

```
Buttons mButtons;
for(int i = 0; i < mButtons.buttons.size(); i++) {
    mButtons.buttons[i] = new QPushButton(mCentralWidget);
    ...
    connect(mButtons.buttons[i], SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), &mButtons, SLOT(getBtnInfo()));
}
```

It runs without any errors; but the `getBtnInfo() slot` seems like not do anything. Because I tried simply just debug in this slot, not working.
But if I declare `getBtnInfo() slot` in `mainwindow.h` and connect like this:

```
connect(mButtons.buttons[i], SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(getBtnInfo()));
```

then it works.
I wonder why? And how do I solve the problem above?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a variable is created in a function it only exists in that function, then it will not be accessible, and that is what I think is happening, I recommend you to make mButtons a member of the class.

***.h**

```
private:
    Buttons mButtons;
```

Comment: I tried what you recommend, but the problem is still there. I do not think that is the solution. BTW, I created the variable and connect the signals and slots in the same function. So do you know any other way to solve that problem?

Comment: @TheodoreTang I have tried to reproduce your project with what you show me and my modifications and it has worked, maybe I have assumed other things, you could share your project please to be able to test it.

Comment: I found after I make mButtons to my class, I forgot to remove the declaration of mButtons in that function. I removed it and it worked. Thanks